# Simple Windows-DNS on LAN

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2016

I setup windows servers mainly for filesharing, with a synology backup for small businesses, but I recently was stumped on DNS. If I have a netgear router doing dhcp, and my windows server handling dns for a local 192.168.1.0/24 subnet, and I point the workstations to that dns server, why wont it resolve local hostnames of devices on the network like synology or workstation10 etc? On my active directory servers this doesnt seem to be an issue. Is it because to get the desired effect the server needs to be running DNS & DHCP? I setup a fqdn like server.office.local and created all the necessary forward and reverse zones for the LAN, but it still didnt work.

Comment: Your AD clients have a primary DNS suffix, which is why they work. Your other clients do not, which is why they don't.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your DNS server allow dynamic update from the DHCP’s client.

If nothing work make sure netbios is activated and the network discovery is on, it will allow netbios to resolve local hostname in your LAN by broadcast.

Comment: Yes dynamic update was on, so was network discovery. The server itself could resolve netbios hostnames even though there was no Active Directory, but if I pointed a workstation to that dns server it would not resolve hosts in the same Lan. Very strange